# Flutter Expanded TextWidget does not take rest of the space left

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` with a `Card` that contains a `Row`. The problem is that the second text is inside a `Expanded` widget, which does not take the space that is clearly empty on the right. If I remove the `FractionallySizedBox`, then both widgets takes upp the available space. So why is the `Expanded` widget behave like a `Flexible`?

```
ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: [
          Card(
            child: Row(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Flexible(child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum est sed fermentum commodo.")),
                Flexible(
                  child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.1,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "Nunc hendrerit cursus ante. Pellentesque at convallis urna. Praesent eu ullamcorper quam. Praesent efficitur est quis arcu porta semper.")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `flex` attribute on the `Flexible` and `Expanded` widgets. Something like this (note I removed the center spacer widget for simplicity)

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  children: [
    Card(
      child: Row(
        children: const <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum est sed fermentum commodo.")
          ),
          Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Text(
                  "Nunc hendrerit cursus ante. Pellentesque at convallis urna. Praesent eu ullamcorper quam. Praesent efficitur est quis arcu porta semper.")),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. There are two ways to expanded it.

1. Add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` inside `Row`
   section
2. Using `flex` property

Your Widget:

```
 ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    children: [
      Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Expanded(
              //  flex: 5,
                child: Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum est sed fermentum commodo.",
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
               // flex: 5,
                child: Text(
                  "Nunc hendrerit cursus ante. Pellentesque at convallis urna. Praesent eu ullamcorper quam. Praesent efficitur est quis arcu porta semper.",
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

1. Refer `Layouts` [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)
2. Refer `Expanded` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)
3. Refer `Flexible` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

Your result screen:-> [image]